# What is the way to isolate HTML/CSS/Javascript without an iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Suppose that I have a blob of HTML, CSS and JS that I wish to repeat on a page.  Logically this blob of HTML/CSS/JS is a "control" and I wish to repeat this control on the page.  Inside this HTML/CSS/JS blob are some IDs, such as tab1, tab2, and tab3 and the JS refers to tab1, tab2 and tab3 using jQuery.

Now of course this works fine when it is repeated only once.  But in order to repeat it more than once and have it not break, I need to change the IDs to something like instance1_tab1, instance2_tab1, instance3_tab1 and so on and also change the Javascript as well.

Now of course I can do this but it feels painful.

So the question is - is there a modern way to simply isolate each of these repeats without using an iFrame?

Right now I am using iFrame to separate them and it is kind of gross so would like to make it better.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Update:** Edited to remove the word "best".  It is not very helpful how the moderators are closing the question as "opinion based" when it is clearly not.  This question does not have a good answer currently on Stackoverflow and is a valuable addition to SO

Comment: perhaps something like this can help: https://github.com/c-smile/spapp

Comment: You could use functions for your JS and turn your `id` into `class` and reference using `this` keyword depending on your runtime binding within each function used. Run loops and iterate using some kind of ticker that will be able to reference your classes nodes.

Comment: As for HTML, you could consider using a back-end language like PHP where you could also create functions saved to an includes file where you could simply include your includes file and then add your functions that create your code blocks of html.

Comment: Also take a look at web components, might be right for your usage.. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components

Comment: Removing "best" doesn't cut it, you are deliberately trying to start a debate. Asking for opinions on how to do something doesn't match the format of this site because you can't definitively award a solution to the question, also every response will be opinion based and will end up in lengthy discussions in the comments. Take this into a chat room or https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com

Comment: @ChrisSchaller I am not trying to start a debate, and there is no evidence to support this claim.  I am asking a technical question, and seeking a technical answer - not opinions.  Instead of getting technical answers, my question has been shut down preventing any answers from being given

Comment: @Abr the problem is that most web client frameworks like Vue, Angular all have solutions for this, even Blazor has a solution. Most use web components, some use server-side rendering. So you need to reduce the scope by specifying which technology stack you are using and show some examples of what you have tried. An object oriented approach to your situation IMO is best, its not about the actual _Ids_ or the repeated sections (unique Ids are often used under the hood either way) but how you manage them. Already in these comments you have attracted such a vast array of solutions

Comment: So you should re-post (don't bother salvaging this one) with a much more focused question. SO isn't a space for advice, its more designed for answers, so re-phrase this in the form of a problem that includes your code attempt and we can provide a solution that is in the style and technology that you are already using

Answer (score 1):

I think, you could look into Web Components. In particular Lit Element library. Web Components encapsulates HTML, CSS and JS into single `custom element`. As example, you can have `<tab-group>` and `<tab-group-tab>` HTML elements. You can pass objects as attributes as well.
If you don't want to use any library, it is still possible, but requires bit more boilerplate.
Browser support is pretty good already and many large companies are adopting web components at scale.
There are link to some examples - https://stackblitz.com/edit/open-wc-lit-demos